# Can two asciidoc file content can be merged into one

Tags: asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I have used spring-rest-docs to generate the documentation for the project. spring-rest-docs generated the snippet with .adoc file extension.
I want to merge the two .adoc file content into one .adoc file which is master.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to merge them, write a third document that includes the generated ones. In this document, you could do global configuration of the asciidoc processor and perhaps provide some additional text or structure to glue the generated content together.

Chapter 28 in the asciidoctor manual describes the [include directive](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#include-directive). The example from section 28.4 on [partitioning large documents](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#include-partitioning) has the following example, where the separate chapters are in distinct files:

```
= My book

include::chapter01.adoc[]

include::chapter02.adoc[]

include::chapter03.adoc[]
```